# How do you insert text into a specific Google spreadsheet by ID using pydrive2?

Tags: google-drive-api, pydrive

I'm trying to write text into a Google spreadsheet, but it appears you can only write into the first tab.

Using this code only allows me to write to the first tab and none of the docs specify how to do it.
https://docs.iterative.ai/PyDrive2/

```
google_file_ref = next(iter(drive.ListFile({'q':f"mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and '{google_file_ref_id}' in parents and trashed=false",
        'maxResults': 10,
        'corpora': 'teamDrive',
        'teamDriveId': drive_id,
        'includeTeamDriveItems': True,
        'supportsTeamDrives': True}).GetList()))
google_file_ref.SetContentString(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
google_file_ref.Upload()
```

Comment: For editing/writing in Google Sheet, you may want to  use separate library for that. Have you consider using [pygsheets](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) or [gspread](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.10.0/)?

Comment: @cnavar - I gave that a shot, but I'm getting a 403 with my service account.

`gclient = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='path/to/file)

gclient.open_by_key('<spreadsheetId>')

Encountered 403 Forbidden with reason "PERMISSION_DENIED"`

Comment: The error that you're getting is about authorization error. Have you done this step [Authorizing pygsheets](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/authorization.html#service-account)?

Comment: Yeah I got to work with the `pygsheets` library, that was a really good suggestion. It's a shame `pydrive2` library isn't as functional handling spreadsheets .